# adding if clause within exception

Tags: python

I have a function that will parse json files. I expect an error **KeyError: 'packDetails'** for some files where a leaf is missing.
I need to call another function if and only if packDetails is missing in the original JSON file.

```
try:
    readmyjson('AVATI_20171013_189527.json')
except Exception as e:
    if 'packDetails' in str(e):
        othermyjson('AVATI_20171013_189527.json')
```

I expected the above try / except block to work, but I get this message:

```
KeyError: 'packDetails'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

How do I handle function using if /else logic within exception?

Comment: I think the problem is not that you use an if statement in an exception but that while handling the exception another exception occurred. So you need to catch that one as well or try to make the handling exception free...

Comment: You caused another exception while handling the first, as the error says. This has nothing to do with the if. Post the full error.

Comment: `othermyjson('AVATI_20171013_189527.json')` raises it and it goes unhandled ofc

Comment: It means I need another try except block to handle othermyjson? Is there any limit on nesting like this?

Comment: If you want to handle exceptions in othermyjson then put an exception handler around that. Maybe that could all be hidden inside a function, though.

Comment: NEVER USE `except Exception` unless you are reraising the exception if it is not one you are handling yourself. If you want to handle `KeyError` use `catch KeyError as e:`

Comment: To answer the first part of your question, an exception that doesn't match the `if` condition will be silently ignored by this code block. To avoid that (i.e. to allow those other exceptions to show an error as usual), add an `else:` clause with one statement: `raise`

Comment: also you should replace `if 'packDetails' in str(e):` by `if 'packDetails' in e.args:`

Comment: You can nest several exception handlers. Although in this case, I suspect the KeyError in othermyjson is a bug, which you should just fix.